# How do you enable the radio graph of your contributions on github

Tags: github

I was talking with a friend today and showed him my github contribution graph. After seeing it he asked how I got the little radio graph that shows the percentage of commits vs pull requests vs issues vs code reviews.

[image]

I remember enabling it in the settings at some point in the past but I cannot remember where I did it. I also looked through the settings just now and I don't see an option for it. Moreover when I search online I can't find any mention of it.

I feel like I'm searching using the wrong term for the graph or something. Anyone know where this feature is enabled??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called Activity Overview. You can enable it here:

https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/managing-contribution-settings-on-your-profile/showing-an-overview-of-your-activity-on-your-profile